# Compile filename.tex file to pdf on terminal

Tags: pdftex

I use a windows computer at school and I'm able to do it. Here's what I do there:

type in Z:
then type in cd myclasscode
then i can finally put in latex filename.tex 
and so on and so on
IT WORKS
but with my mac nooooooo (I only downloaded the smaller package because I couldn't wait for a long while but I downloaded the other parts too)

Can you please send a step by step procedure for this...

Comment: The `Z:` part may not work on your Mac. Please provide more information about your problem? What exactly does not work? What is the error you receive if any? How did you install TeX on your machine? Maybe http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line and http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/ can help if you have trouble with the command line?